# JavaScript plotting vectors, curves and points in 3D with animation

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plot

I am looking for a way to plot spheres, arrows (vectors), points and curves in 3D using JavaScript. Ideally the generated plot should be capable to be rotated, zoomed, paned and tilted by the user. Furthermore, I would like to create animations (e.g., an arrow that rotates around an axis). I feel a little lost how to start.

Here is an example of what I have in mind:
[image: Sphere with dots and arrow]

Answer (score 3):

I think you should give [three.js](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Creating-a-scene) a try.

Here is a simple example that will draw a wireframe sphere with an arrow:

[image: Animated three.js wireframe sphere]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.137.5/build/three.js"></script>
    <script>
      const scene = new THREE.Scene();
      const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
        75,
        window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
        0.1,
        1000
      );

      const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

      const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
      const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });

      const sphereRadius = 3;
      const sphereXSegments = 20;
      const sphereYSegments = 20;
      const sphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.SphereGeometry(
          sphereRadius,
          sphereXSegments,
          sphereYSegments
        ),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, wireframe: true })
      );
      scene.add(sphereMesh);

      const arrowDirectionVector = new THREE.Vector3(-0.4, 0, 1);
      arrowDirectionVector.normalize();
      const arrowOrigin = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
      const arrowLength = 3;
      const arrowColorHex = 0x1100ff;
      const arrowHelper = new THREE.ArrowHelper(
        arrowDirectionVector,
        arrowOrigin,
        arrowLength,
        arrowColorHex
      );
      scene.add(arrowHelper);

      camera.position.z = 5;
      camera.position.y = 1;
      camera.rotation.x = (3.141 / 180) * -10; // 20 deg

      function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        sphereMesh.rotation.y += 0.001;
        //sphereMesh.rotation.x += 0.001;
        //sphereMesh.rotation.y += 0.001;

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
      }

      animate();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's a working demo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.137.5/build/three.js"></script>
    <script>
      const scene = new THREE.Scene();
      const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
        75,
        window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
        0.1,
        1000
      );

      const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

      const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
      const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });

      const sphereRadius = 3;
      const sphereXSegments = 20;
      const sphereYSegments = 20;
      const sphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.SphereGeometry(
          sphereRadius,
          sphereXSegments,
          sphereYSegments
        ),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, wireframe: true })
      );
      scene.add(sphereMesh);

      const arrowDirectionVector = new THREE.Vector3(-0.4, 0, 1);
      arrowDirectionVector.normalize();
      const arrowOrigin = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
      const arrowLength = 3;
      const arrowColorHex = 0x1100ff;
      const arrowHelper = new THREE.ArrowHelper(
        arrowDirectionVector,
        arrowOrigin,
        arrowLength,
        arrowColorHex
      );
      scene.add(arrowHelper);

      camera.position.z = 5;
      camera.position.y = 1;
      camera.rotation.x = (3.141 / 180) * -10; // 20 deg

      function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        sphereMesh.rotation.y += 0.001;
        //sphereMesh.rotation.x += 0.001;
        //sphereMesh.rotation.y += 0.001;

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
      }

      animate();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code works as it is in the SO snippet. I added it, with the text *"here's a working demo"*, feel free to rollback my edit.

Comment: Thanks, I've forgotten of the feature :)